# Socket I.o doesn't automatically update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, websocket, socket.io

I am using the Socket ith and when I send a POST / EnviaTemperatura is not updating automatically on my site. what am I doing wrong?

**Node.js**

```
app.post('/EnviaTemperatura', function(req, res){
    temperatura = req.body.temp;
    console.log(temperatura);
    res.send('Temperatura: ' + temperatura);
});

io.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.emit('RecebTemp', temperatura);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
    <div class="huge"><span id="EnviaTemp">0</span> ºC</div>
    <div>Temperatura no Interior da casa</div>
</div>

<script>
    var socket = io();
        socket.on('RecebTemp', function (temperatura) { 
            document.getElementById("EnviaTemp").innerHTML = temperatura;
        });
</script>
```

In my case, it is only updating when I the one Refresh the page. But I did not want to refresh the entire page, only that DIV, as have other elements on the screen that take a while to load.

What could it be?

Comment: The temperatura is received correctly in socket.on in front-end? If yes, instead getElementById("EnviaTemp").innerHTML try getElementById("EnviaTemp").textContent = temperatura

Comment: It's because the server sends the variable `temperatura` only once, on connection.

Comment: @mk12ok how i change this?

Comment: how do you update the variable `temperatura` ? Where does the data come from, the client?

Comment: @mk12ok from a Post request in Node.js. Its a post then will receive data each 5 seconds

Comment: Let's emit an event 'newTemp' when we receive new data. And let's add socket.on('newTemp', ...) inside io.on('connection', ...)

Comment: @mk12ok i think this is not a solution. In Socket will send automatically with my code. I need to change the io.on('connection) for other class to refresh, but i doesn't know that class

Comment: Let me understand the problem. You have two clients and one of them sends POST every 5 seconds to the server. Then the server should send the temperature to the second client. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
'use strict';
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const temperatureSender = new MyEmitter();
```

and then inside the app.post:

```
temperatureSender.emit( 'sendTemp', temperature);
```

and inside the io.on('connection',..):

```
temperatureSender.on('sendTemp', function(temperature) {
    socket.emit('RecebTemp', temperature);
});
```

Comment: I wrote a simple system, similar to yours, and it works like a charm. Let me know how you are doing